# Convert Vue route param title to id

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm creating a course website and each course has its own page.
Let's say I open course number 1, then the link is http://localhost:8080/course/1 . I want to change it to http://localhost:8080/course/course-name-here . My problem is, when I change the param, the data isn't fetched from the API.

index.js

```
{
    path: '/courses',
    name: 'Courses',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/Courses.vue')
},
{
    path: '/course/:id',
    name: 'CourseDetail',
    props: true,
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/CourseDetail.vue')
}
```

CourseList.vue

```
<v-row>
   <v-col sm="6" md="4" v-for="course in courses" v-bind:key="course.courseId">
      <router-link v-bind:to="{name: 'CourseDetail', params: {id: course.courseTitle}}" class="text-decoration-none">
         <VerticalCard v-bind:course="course"/>
      </router-link>
   </v-col>
</v-row>
```

CourseDetail.vue (script)

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  props:['id'],
  data: function(){
    return {
      singleCourse: null,
      selectedIndex: null,
      showPage: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      var that = this
      axios.get('http://my-api-here.amazonaws.com/v1/api/course?id=' + this.id,
            {
              headers: {
                'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + this.$store.state.authKey 
              }
            })
            .then(function(response) {
              that.singleCourse = response.data.body
            })
      },
      show() {
        if(this.$store.state.isLogin == true){
          this.showPage = true
        }
        else {
          this.$router.replace('/login')
        }
      }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.getData()
    this.show()
  }
}
```

example of a singleCourse

```
{ "_id": { "$oid": "5fc63dab36d8491476999831" }, 
"courseTitle": "Python For Everybody", 
"createdDate": { "$date": 1606852635135 }, 
"creator": "Admin", 
"courseId": 1, 
"courseDesc": "Description Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing", 
"courseCategory": "Programming", 
"courseImage": "https://cwpwp2.betterthanpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/2-1-1.jpg", 
"syllabus": [ { "chapterName": "Introduction to Python 3 Programming Tutorial", "chapterVideo": "eXBD2bB9-RA" }] }
```

Comment: The API seems to need the `id` param so how would it work if you stop passing it?

Comment: Yes, I know that. That's why I'm confused on how to get the title from API (since the API needs id), and then set it as the route params. Or is it really not possible to do so? @Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object to look up each course's id by the name.  Pass the `title` param instead of `id` (change to `title` in the route, link, and prop).  In the component:

```js
data() {
  return {
    courseIds: {
      'course-name-here': 1,
      'other-course': 2,
      'one-more': 3
    }
  }
}
```

Use this in `getData()`:

```js
getData() {
   ...
   const url = 'http://my-api-here.amazonaws.com/v1/api/course?id=';
   axios.get(url + this.courseIds[this.title])
   ...
}
```

You could keep the lookup data in Vuex instead if other modules / components need access to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But does it mean I have to hardcode all the `courseIds`?

Comment: You're welcome.  The lookup needs to be somewhere, not necessarily in the app though.  Maybe your api provides a list that you could convert into that format.  You could even keep it in a JSON file if you prefer

Comment: Oooh, I see. Not sure if I'm gonna go with it because my website also has a feature for users to post a course. There's no way I'm gonna hardcode all of the courses. But, thank you so so much for your explanation. Much appreciated!

Comment: That should be alright.  Your system would generate an id when they post a course, and you enter both title and id into the database / JSON file, etc.  It doesn't have to be hardcoded.  But somewhere the app needs to be able to get an id from a name, or it's just not possible to pass the id to the api